# Plain TypeScript tuple missing '[Symbol.iterator]()' method in bazel ts_library

Tags: typescript, bazel

I'm trying to compile this TypeScript code in a Bazel `ts_library` target:

```
function distance(
  a: [number, number, number],
  b: [number, number, number]
): number {
  let [x1, y1, z1] = a;
  let [x2, y2, z2] = b;
  return Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2 + (z1 - z2) ** 2);
}
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
error TS2488: Type '[number, number, number]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

16   let [x1, y1, z1] = a;
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The same function compiles just fine in the TypeScript Playground. There must be something wrong with the Bazel `ts_library` setup but I can't figure out what. My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Recommended"
}
```

I'm also getting the same error for a simple number array literal, e.g.:

```
for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

produces this error:

```
error TS2488: Type 'number[]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.

5 for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) {
                ~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Add `"lib": ["es2015"],` to `compilerOptions` and see if that helps?

Comment: `"lib": ["es2015"],` did the trick! Thanks @PatrickRoberts!